# Uploading inserts values on db, stores file in folder buts doesnt play the file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i did a script that uploads a file to a folder, stores the value in db and then displays it. All these are ok, the file is uploaded in the folder, the value is inserted in the db and the display is as wanted but the problem is when i play the file mp3 from the doesnt play it says corrupt file or wrong extension. The file is not corrupted it plays before i start the uploading process

ts

```
   onSubmit() {

let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'crescent',
    dismissOnPageChange: true
});

loader.present();
this.media.audioFile = this.fileData;
this.media.browser = true;
const media = new FormData();
media.append('file', this.fileData);
this.userData.uploadAudio(this.media) 
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
    loader.dismiss(); 


    if (data.success) {
        swal({
            icon: "success",
            text: data.message,
            buttons: {
                visible: false
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        swal({
            icon: "error",
            text: data.error,
            buttons: {
                visible: false
            }
        });
    }
},
err => {
    loader.dismiss();
    alert('An error occurred, please check your internet connection');
});
   }
```

html

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Choose File</h3>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="file"  />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any answer on this?

Comment: i think the problem is on formData